# Handling non DB mapped fields in results from JPA/DAO Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dao, dto

Currently we have 3 types of POJO objects on our system:

@Entity - DO database objects (Read-Write mapped objects to Tables)

@Entity - View objects (read only mapped objects to SELECT statements)

Model - Non ORM objects for presentation purposes

There are instances where we need to fetch view-object and add/edit couple of fields manually and send to presentation, in the service layer. 
Is it ok to do that using view objects , by adding dummy fields mapped to dummy columns ('' as dummyField in select statements).

Understand hibernate/jpa will try and flush the objects on end of transaction context, which will give error on table not found. We are able to work-around this using @Transactional (readonly=true).

Are there any drawbacks to this? Instead of creating a whole new model and populating the view with that?

Comment: `which will give error on table not found` what? If you read from a table, then that table exists. Also, once you leave a transaction, no changes are flushed back to the database automatically. You would need to manually call `update()` to write back any changes

Comment: XtremeBaumer - What you said is true for the first set of objects, objects mapped to a DB table.

The View objects are @Entity objects mapped to SELECT statements, which may have columns from multiple tables and columns that are computed. In which case there is no physical table.

Comment: Then users shouldn't have to possibility to edit those entities. They should only be able to view them

Comment: Clarification on my post above: The "manually adding/editing" refers to java code in service layer adding additional info to the View objects retrieved using @Entity.  Not the end users on UI side.

Answer (score 0):

> by adding dummy fields mapped to dummy columns ( as dummyField in select statements)

you don't need to have hibernate populate the fields at all and can leave the sql alone, just annotate non persisted fields with `@javax.persistence.Transient`

> flush the objects on end of transaction context

It will flush any time it sees fit, e.g. before any other query in order to get a consistent result set

> which will give error on table not found

Bizarre. But you don't seriously want to take a view model to read **and** write I suppose. So `@Transactional (readonly=true)` is the way to go anyway.

> Are there any drawbacks to this? Instead of creating a whole new model

Aside from software-ideological arguments you mean? The approach creates a bit of confusion it seems, and obviously the hibernate peculiarities leak out of the service layer.

But if you get it right on a technical level, you get the behavior you want and spare some back-and-forth mapping overhead.

Comment: using @javax.persistence.Transient seem to be more elegant solution. Will this cause any issues if you were to cache those objects in say second level cache like redis or ehcache?

Comment: Can't see a reason why it would. Liability excluded, of course.